# tmpl.Execute and sub-file golang

Tags: templates, go

I need help.
I need to use `"html/template"`'s marking (`{{.Title}}`, example) in sub-files(`"article.html"`, example in my text):

```
// ...
type Page struct {
    Test string
}

type News struct {
    Page
    Title string
}

func main() {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles(filepath+"core.tmpl", filepath+"article.tmpl")
    p := &News{
        Title: "TITLE",
        Page: Page{
            Test: "TITLE",
        },
    }
    t.Execute(wr, p)
}
```

Code in `core.tmpl`:

```
{{template "article"}}
```

Code in `article.tmpl`:

```
{{define "article"}}
{{.Title}}<br><br>
{{.Page.Test}}
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `core.tmpl` you have to use

```
{{template "article" .}}
```

If you don't specify the `.` at the end, the template will be executed with `nil` data. Specifying the `.` will pass the value of `.` to the invoked template.

Quoting from the [`text/template`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package documentation, `Actions` section:

```
{{template "name"}}
    The template with the specified name is executed with nil data.

{{template "name" pipeline}}
    The template with the specified name is executed with dot set
    to the value of the pipeline.
```